# approximating a sphere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose that $R$ is a simple connected region in $\mathbb{R}^3$, enclosing a volume $V$. I am looking at ways to approximate $V$ using spheroidal volume elements. The traditional approach is to use cuboids for volume elements, and then to determine a Riemann sum leading to an iterated integral. I'm looking for literature where this sort of idea has been explored. I would also like to know whether it makes sense to approximate a spheroid by a cuboid.